# Where is shipping cost configured in Sitecore Commerce?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

Where can I View/Configure the data related to shipping Charges that is visible on the Storefront at checkout ? I want to change the default shipping cost values to my custom values. Please help me out with a way of doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should configure GlobalPhysicalFulfillmentPolicy inside commerce engine services.

Do following:

1. Open folder CommerceAuthoring\wwwroot\data\Environments folder.
2. Open environment files e.g. PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json and PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceShops-1.0.0.json.
3. Search policy "GlobalPhysicalFulfillmentPolicy" inside it and configure the correct amount values. (make sure you do the changes in correct environment files).
4. Using Postman bootstrap commerce engine again.
5. Restart IIS AppPools for Commerce engine services.

Try placing order in storefront, you should be able see the new amount.

Comment: Hi Vipin, 
This was very helpful. I'm really thankful for your effort in answering my question.
Can you please let me know where to find the discount values in the same regard?

Comment: I will try to answer but please create a separate question.

Comment: I tried the same steps to change the shipping values but ended up with [No catalog Data found] on the storefront after I bootstrap the commerce engine. Any workaround for this? I tried creating the tenant again and reindexed everything. But it didn't work for me. Can you please help me out with this issue.

Comment: is your commerce service up and running after bootstrap, can you see catalog in sitecore content editor?

Comment: yes, my commerce service is up and running..
I see the catalog in sitecore content tree but not any child items to it.

Comment: check your sitecore logs or commerce engine logs, there may be some issue