# Where is Discount configured in Sitecore Commerce?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

Where do I find/configure/change the discount values that appear on the default sxa storefront on checkout? [image]

Comment: What kind of discount values you mean? Taxes?

Comment: please see these youtube videos from master sitecore youtube channel to get some understanding of pricing, discounts and coupons.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFZDKHQaVK8, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q2M8_H17UE, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qooGOZxKMRE

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou, 
I mean the discount values which show up on the calculations in the checkout page. I have updated the question with a screenshot for reference.

Comment: If you are talking about screenshot from https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22072/where-is-shipping-cost-configured-in-sitecore-commerce in that case, looks like you have FreeShipping discount. You can find in Promotion manager related promotion and manage it.